# PhpStorm Live Edit feature not working? [PhpStorm 2020.2]

Tags: javascript, html, phpstorm, jetbrains-ide, liveedit

I use VS Code + 'Live Server' plug-in very often so everytime I save, the project will be refreshed automatically.

Today I was playing around with PhpStorm, newest version with legit subscription license (I've been using phpstorm for couple years) but it seemed that 'Live Edit' plug-in not working even I tried to look it up on internet. However, none of them helped!

I appreciate any help! Thanks

**What I did:**

- Installed Jetbrains IDE extension on Chrome
- Installed 'Live Edit' plug in on PhpStorm
- Settings as below:

[image]

Comment: First of all, you don't need the Chrome extension for that, so please disable the corresponding option and remove the extension. Then, what kind of code do you edit and expect it to be updated in browser - is it JS, CSS, HTML?

Comment: yes only that three. I tried both, with and without Chrome extension. Same thing

Comment: I meant with which of them doesn't it work? What changes aren't shown? 
If you change JS code that is executed only on page load (and not on certain event like button click), you have to manually reload the page to see the results - live edit doesn't force new code execution.

Answer (score 2):

To Live Edit feature works only when the JavaScript debug session is started for the URL your app is running on.

To start one, in the menu Run - Edit Configurations, create a new config of the type JavaScript Debug and specify the URL of your app (e.g. localhost:3000). Save the config and start the debugger.

To use Live Edit for an .html file, you can also use the IDE built-in server and start debugger – right-click on the file in project view or editor and select `Debug filename.html`.